# How to remove .php extension, redirect old files to new files and force SSL in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I searched this on Stackoverflow and web many times but I couldn't find a one that does this all, that's why I'm asking this question.

For one of my new project, I decided to remove `.php` file extensions from URLS.

Using .htaccess

I want to

1. Force SSL
2. Redirect `www` URLs to `non-www`
3. Remove `.php` file extension from my URLS
4. Redirect old `.php` URLS to new non URLS
5. Add trailing slash after URL `/`

This is what I tried but trailing slash and ssl is not working properly. I do not know if I'm using the right order.

To force SSL

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

WWW to non WWW

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Remove and trailing slash

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Redirect extension files to non extension.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.php(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php$ http://www.example.com/yourdirectory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How to achieve this in the best way? Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not try to put it together from the other answers, and come back when you hit specific issue? No-one is going to write this for you...

Comment: I did copied all of this in this order but trailing slash and WWW is not working. That's why I decided to ask because I do not know which order to use.

Comment: Then share your code and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I will include it in my post now. I'm editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect `.php` requests to a clean URL with `.php` removed:

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

To force SSL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This will force a trailing slash.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
   RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying this now. Do I have to use Rewrite Engine again on last one?

Comment: No, one `RewriteEngine On` entry is enough. Kept it on both since I was separating the use cases.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I used this and it says on chrome, 
redirected you too many times.

Comment: my mistake it should has been ^www\.